# how to stretch the icon in google map api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is my code...
The problem is, I don't know how to stretch the image of icon. 
I just want to know if there's a way to stretch the image of icon? if there is, please tell me..thanks in advance

```
var image = {
    url: 'images/arrive.png'
    size: new google.maps.Size(40, 40)
};

var markerOptions = {
  map: map, 
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longti), 
  icon: image};
```

Comment: do you want to resize marker image?

Comment: no. i want to strecth it. so that, when i resize the icon image it is still view as full size.

Answer (score 3):

Use Like

```
 var icon = {
     url: "../res/sit_marron.png", // url
     size: new google.maps.Size(width, height), // size
     origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
     anchor: new google.maps.Point(anchor_left, anchor_top) // anchor 
 };

 position = new google.maps.LatLng(latitud,longitud)
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: position,
  map: map,
  icon: icon
 });
```

[Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons)

Comment: whats the purpose of origin and anchor? i tried it earlier but my image just move inch in the original position.

Comment: anchor : The position at which to anchor an image in correspondance to the location of the marker on the map. By default, the anchor is located along the center point of the bottom of the image. origin : The position of the image within a sprite, if any. By default, the origin is located at the top left corner of the image (0, 0).

Answer (score 3):

Use `scaledSize` Property of Google Maps API.

The size of the entire image after scaling, if any. Use this property to stretch/shrink an image or a sprite.

You can see here about [scaledSize](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerImage) .

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your code,

```
 origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
 anchor: new google.maps.Point(anchor_left, anchor_top)
```